# "Too many Calendar deletes" error by Android calendar provider

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am using calendar provider to create and delete events.

The problem occurs in some devices when I try to remove events. Android OS shows a notification saying:

> "Too many Calendar deletes"

with options to proceed.

I couldn't find an answer to fix it in Android, only read about calendar API limitation. But it's unacceptable to offer a feature to clientes with this notification.

I am running the following line to remove an event:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(eventUri, null, null);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, there is no "correct" way to bypass this message and you also shouldn't even try. This is shown because the sync adapter has set the [tooManyDeletions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncResult.html#tooManyDeletions) flag in the [SyncResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncResult.html) object to `true` after trying to sync.
The sync manager will always show this message if the flag is set to `true`.

The number of allowed deletions is defined by the respective sync adapter or by the API it's syncing to. So if you see the message depends on the account type and maybe even on the version of the sync adapter.

This is a mechanism to protect the user's data from being deleted due to a mistake (either by himself or by broken software).

You could try to trick the SyncManager and the sync adapter by triggering a sync on the respective account with the [SYNC_EXTRAS_OVERRIDE_TOO_MANY_DELETIONS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#SYNC_EXTRAS_OVERRIDE_TOO_MANY_DELETIONS) flag being set by your code, **but you really shouldn't do that**. Actually I would consider this a bug in Android if it works.

You should communicate this to the user and sell it as a feature.

#### Update:

To trigger a sync with `SYNC_EXTRAS_OVERRIDE_TOO_MANY_DELETIONS` call this:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_OVERRIDE_TOO_MANY_DELETIONS, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(accountOfCalendar, CalendarContract.Authority, extras);
```

`accountOfCalendar` is the account of the calendar that you deleted the events from.

Use it with care.

Comment: I am using a local calendar, why I should not  try to override deletions? I am adding the events in my app, so I have to be able to control deletion too. User is accepting app rules when he installs the app and I am only manage my app events. Do you know how to integrate SYNC_EXTRAS_OVERRIDE_TOO_MANY_DELETIONS with context.getContentResolver().delete(...) ?

Comment: Mostly because your app as no idea which other events have been removed. The flag will affect all events that have been deleted from that account, not only the events created and deleted by your app. Even if your app works as intended, another app may misbehave and delete the user's events. If you override this safety feature he has no chance to cancel the operation.

Comment: The flag is a sync flag. You don't apply it to the delete operation. Instead you need to trigger a sync yourself, right after you've deleted the events and before the SyncManager does it. Usually there is plenty of time to do that (about 5-10 seconds after the first operation completed). The SyncManager may filter the flag before passing the extras on to the sync adapter. If that's the case you need to control the deletion rate and trigger a sync after every few deletes and wait before you continue.

Comment: Thanks Marten. Can you show me a bit example? I can't understand how to trigger it. Thanks again!